# JQuery and PHP unique Chat window for each user and database saved chat history

Tags: php, jquery

I managed to create the chat windows open uniquely depending on what user is clicked but I cannot send messages on any chat window except the first one.

I am trying to achieve this:
[image]

I am trying to achieve exactly that ^

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script> //CHAT SYSTEM
    function chatWith(id, status, username){ 
        $("#chats").append('<div class="chat_window" id="chat_'+id+'"><div class="chat_top"><span class="chat_username">'+status+username+'</span><span class="chat_x"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="minChat('+id+')">-</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeChat('+id+')">X</a>  </span> </div>  <div class="chat_content"></div> <form method="post" name="chat" action=""> <textarea class="chat_text" maxlength="200" name="chat_text" id="chat_text_'+id+'" placeholder="Start typing..."></textarea> </form> </div></dv>'); 
        $("#chat_"+id).slideToggle("fast");             
    } 

    //send messages
    var user_id = '<?php echo $session_user_id;?>';
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
        var b = $("#chat_"+user_id+":last").attr("id");     
        $.getJSON("chat.php?user_id="+user_id,function(data){
            $.each(data.posts, function(i,data) {               
                if(b != data.id)  { 
                    var div_data="<span id='"+data.id+"'>"+data.user_id+": "+data.msg+"</span>";                        
                    $(div_data).appendTo("#chat_"+user_id);
                }
            });
        });
    }, 2000);   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                var boxval = $(".chat_text").val();                 
                var user_id = '<?php echo $session_user_id;?>';
                var dataString = 'user_id='+ user_id + '&msg=' + boxval;

                if(boxval.length > 0) { 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "chat.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){                     
                            $(".chat_content").append(html);
                            $(".chat_text").val('');
                            $(".chat_text").focus();
                            $(".chat_content").animate({scrollTop: $(".chat_text").offset().top}, 500);
                        }
                    });             
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

this is my chat.php

```
  if($_POST){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat(user_id, msg) VALUES ('$user_id', '$msg')");

    $chat_results = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1"));

    echo '<span style="font-size:0.9em;font-weight:bold;">'.$chat_results['username'].'</span>: <span style="font-size:0.9em;">'.$msg.'</span><br>';
}
if($_GET['user_id']){
    $user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
    $row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat order by id desc limit 1"));
    $user_idx = $row['user_id'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $msg = $row['msg'];
    if($user_idx != $user_id){
        echo '{"posts": [{  "id":"'.$id.'", "user_id":"'.$user_idx.'", "msg":"'.$msg.'" },]}';
    } 
}
```

and the div it all opens on:

```
<div id="chats"> 

</div>
```

Will really appreciate any help, been breaking my head on this for weeks now!

Comment: there is a typo at the end of $("#chats").append(...</dv> must be </div>

Answer (score 5):

your problem is here:

```
            var boxval = $(".chat_text").val(); //<-- here it is                
            ...

            $(".chat_content").append(html);//<-- here it is  
            $(".chat_text").val('');//<-- here it is  
            $(".chat_text").focus();//<-- here it is  
            $(".chat_content").animate({scrollTop: $(".chat_text").offset().top}, 500);//<-- here it is
```

its obvious that each "chat window" has the classes ".chat_content",".chat_text"

so how should your js be able to guess which one is the right ? So it obviously takes only the first occurrence what would explain it works only in the first window.

So 1000 ways to Rome

i will recommend one:

at very first correct the chatWith append, the last

```
 </dv>
```

is unnesesary and must be removed

```
function chatWith(id, status, username){ 
    $("#chats").append('<div class="chat_window" id="chat_'+id+'"><div class="chat_top"><span class="chat_username">'+status+username+'</span><span class="chat_x"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="minChat('+id+')">-</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeChat('+id+')">X</a>  </span> </div>  <div class="chat_content"></div> <form method="post" name="chat" action=""> <textarea class="chat_text" maxlength="200" name="chat_text" id="chat_text_'+id+'" placeholder="Start typing..."></textarea> </form> </div>'); 
    $("#chat_"+id).slideToggle("fast");             
}
```

then you first need to send the correct value
you rather delegate the keypress to the textareas and not the document like

```
$(document).on('keypress','.chat_text',function(e){ //<-- heres the event context passed as argument now, just like you did (copy) yourself
  if(e.which == 13) {
    //wow,now you have the correct textarea in this-context 
    //dont loose it 
    $current=$(this);
    var boxval = $current.val();
    // and prove it!!
    console.log("the currently entered text is: "+boxval);

    //should be correct, now the requesting and appending part
    var user_id = '<?php echo $session_user_id;?>';
    var dataString = 'user_id='+ user_id + '&msg=' + boxval;
    // prove it ! 
    console.log("dataString is: "+dataString+" and therefore correct");
    if(boxval.length > 0) { 
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chat.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){  
                    // better prove if user_id is really correct:
                    console.log("box that will be filled is from user id: "+html.user_id);   
                    // now you have the userid on which you can match to the 
                    // id of the generated chat windows like in answer above mentioned                   
                    $boxToBeFilled=$("#chat_" + html.user_id);

                    $boxToBeFilled.append(boxval);
                    $boxToBeFilled.find('textarea').val('').focus();
                    $boxToBeFilled.children(".chat_content").animate({scrollTop: $(this).find(".chat_text").offset().top}, 500);
            }
        });             
    }
 } 
});
```

there you go

Comment: But now the 'enter' key doens't work as you removed it from the code which means I can't even send my message

Comment: i cant see its beeing removed ? what do you mean ? if i removed it you  could even send the message on every key, i dont get what you mean, pls xplain

Comment: it wasn't there but I saw that you edited the answer so it's there now. I copied the exact code you posted (adding a ; after return false) and it won't sent the message in the chat box :/ in the concole i get "e" is not defined

Comment: i forgot to pass the event argument, updated answer and left comment in code for you to understand and recognize, ofcourse i dont debug or even execute this ;) i just want to help you and let you get an idea whats wrong ;-D

Comment: now it doesn't let me type even!! ah! i really appreciate your help i am trying to do this chat for about a month

Comment: remove the "return false;"

Comment: okay it is typing now but will not send the message on 'enter'

Comment: i made another update, this time i even tryed out the code and it works for me, pls give feedback whats not working

Comment: missing userid querystring from post in example, try adding that @Gadgetster

Comment: @johnSmith I am not sure what I am missing, but I copied your code and removed the div like you said and it still won't send the message when i press 'enter'. @ JFit, I check all the queries and they all seem to have it, where exactly do you mean?

Comment: sorry i cant help you :D do you verify that it logs the correct message to be sent ? then you should be able to trace it until you have the correct solution, you are not far away, i just gave you the idea whats wrong with your code and how you can fix it

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar kind of problem when i was making a comment system on my website.

The first thing.

You are appending the content in the divs having same class attributes.

Change the class attributes like this

```
<script> //CHAT SYSTEM
function chatWith(id, status, username){ 
    $("#chats").append('<div class="chat_window_'+id+'" id="chat_'+id+'"><div class="chat_top_'+id+'"><span class="chat_username">'+status+username+'</span><span class="chat_x"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="minChat('+id+')">-</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeChat('+id+')">X</a>  </span> </div>  <div class="chat_content_'+id+'"></div> <form method="post" name="chat" action=""> <textarea class="chat_text_'+id+'" maxlength="200" name="chat_text" id="chat_text_'+id+'" placeholder="Start typing..."></textarea> </form> </div></div>'); 
    $("#chat_"+id).slideToggle("fast");             
} 

//send messages
var user_id = '<?php echo $session_user_id;?>';
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var b = $("#chat_"+id).attr("id");     
    $.getJSON("chat.php?user_id="+user_id,function(data){
        $.each(data.posts, function(i,data) {               
            if(b != data.id)  { 
                var div_data="<span id='"+data.id+"'>"+data.user_id+": "+data.msg+"</span>";                        
                $(div_data).appendTo("#chat_"+id);
            }
        });
    });
}, 2000);   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var boxval = $(".chat_text_'+id+'").val();                 
            var user_id = '<?php echo $session_user_id;?>';
            var dataString = 'user_id='+ user_id + '&msg=' + boxval;

            if(boxval.length > 0) { 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "chat.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){                     
                        $(".chat_content_'+id+'").append(html);
                        $(".chat_text_'+id+'").val('');
                        $(".chat_text_'+id+'").focus();
                        $(".chat_content_'+id+'").animate({scrollTop:    $(".chat_text_'+id+'").offset().top}, 500);
                    }
                });             
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I fixed all the ".chat_text_'+id+'" to ".chat_text_"+id, still though, i can type in the message but can't send it on 'enter', it just skips to the next line in the message area

Comment: I want to give the 200 points to one of the answers but no body is helping all the way and the code doesn't work. could you please take a look? there are 4 hours left to give away the 200 points!

Comment: still won't send the message on 'enter'

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your questions one by one as follow.

> I managed to create the chat windows open uniquely depending on what
>   user is clicked but I cannot send messages on any chat window except
>   the first one.

When you attempt to append a message you should assign the content to a specific Chat Box. Let's first have an unique ID attribute for each **chat_window** class like:

```
<div id="chats"> 
<div class="chat_window" id="chat_4321"></div> 
</div>
```

This way you know exactly what windows are specific to what users. Returning a JSON of POST Request, you tell to client that the content needs to append to your ID only:

```
if($_POST){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat(user_id, msg) VALUES ('$user_id', '$msg')");

    $chat_results = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1"));
    $json_response = [
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'user_name' => $chat_results['username'],
      'message' => $msg
    ];
    echo json_encode($json_response);
}
```

And your JavaScript

```
if(boxval.length > 0) { 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "chat.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(json){                     
                            $("#chat_" + json.user_id).append(boxval); // Or json.message
                            $("#chat_" + json.user_id).find('textarea').val('').focus();
                            $("#chat_" + json.user_id).children(".chat_content").animate({scrollTop: $(this).find(".chat_text").offset().top}, 500);
                        }
                    });             
                }
```

This depends on how you format that **boxval** variable and of course there are many ways you can achieve your needs. But before having this Chat System I recommend you to take a look at some APIs like [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) or [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) and also concepts like *Long Polling*, *WebSockets*, *Node.js*, *Comet*. However if you got misunderstandings feel free to ask.

Good luck!

Comment: didn't I already do this with <div class="chat_window" id="chat_'+id+'"> ? and the rest of the code doesn't let me even send a message through for some reason